# Read a java "Queue" from multiple theads with all objects in each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

Is there a standard or third party implementation of the java.util.Queue which allows me to read a queue concurrently in multiple threads but delivers all objects to all threads.

Objective is to do multiple parallel processing of messages being regularly added to in a queue. Some processes are fast while others slow. We need all messages to be processed by all threads.

Comment: If all objects are in each thread, would it be better for each thread to have its own queue, and when adding an item, add it to the queue of all threads?

Comment: That will duplicate the storage. Was wondering if there is an implementation that uses a single backing store but maintains separate pointers for each thread

Comment: It won't duplicate the storage since each queue will be looking at the same object.

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Comment: yes Steve understand. But still its duplicating all those references. Plus its an overhead during addition. Nearly 50 threads dealing with tens of thousands of objects. 
And ConcurrentLinkedQueue does not offer independent views per thread

Comment: if every thread will get all same data,the queue must always contain all element.If queue contains all elements you can use a map to record thread consume position.

Answer (score 0):

This task is solved in the libraries which support [Reactive Streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_Streams) initiative, e.g [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). As far as I know, all they support only asynchronous producers and consumers, not threads. But I belive it is easy to create adaptors from asynchronous (non-bloking) to synchronous (blocking) way of communication. And probably the asynchronous solution is better in your case.